# I created a Windows To Go hard drive and it requires legacy boot

Tags: boot, usb, mbr, efi, windows-to-go

I used [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 6.0](http://www.disk-partition.com/) to create a Windows To Go hard drive (MBR, 4 partitions, Toshiba USB 3.0 v73600-H 2TB)

[Click for screenshot.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ign7ecurifv2cwo/disk.png?dl=0)

---

I am able to boot to my hard drive, but *only* in legacy BIOS mode. when I put my PC in legacy BIOS mode, I can boot to the Windows To Go hard drive just fine, but then my PC won't boot to the internal hard drive. I want to convert the Windows To Go drive to UEFI, otherwise, I won't be able to use it on other PCs without modifying the settings, which completely eliminates the point. Is there any way to make my external hard drive or Windows To Go support UEFI?

---

UPDATE: I previously used GPT and it did not work. I will convert if necessary, but you have to tell me what to do after that point.

Comment: MBR = Legacy when dealing with Windows.  If you want EFI mode you would have to be sure GPT is used.

Comment: "Is there any way to make my external hard drive or Windows To Go support UEFI?" - Convert it like it was a physical HDD.  How you go about converting MBR to GPT without data loss is documented

Comment: use rufus the next time here you can select to use GPT: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: GPT conversion won't help you (unless you are talking about a full re-installation). You need the Windows UEFI bootloader to be properly installed on an FAT-formatted partition. Have you tried my answer or did you downvote for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bcdboot.exe` to install the Windows UEFI bootloader to an available FAT32 partition:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Assume `I:` is available to be the EFI System Partition:
`bcdboot.exe H:\Windows /s I: /f UEFI`

No MBR to GPT conversion necessary, as long as your UEFI is standard-conforming enough.

Comment: I did a little research and I figured out the fat32 partition needed to be at the start of the hard drive. P.S. I'm not the one who downvoted and after moving the partitions I will try this.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! After creating an EFI partition at the beginning of the drive and assigning it a letter, I executed this command and now I can boot successfully. I need 15 rep to upvote your answer, though.

Comment: No worries. Glad that it helped.